# How to have an image embedded on an image button scale to the size of the image

Tags: android, user-interface, android-imagebutton

I am attempting to create a calculator app, I would like to use an image button to allow the user to select what they want to calculate. I want to use this image for the 0 button ([zero button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e4NN.png)). Currently when I add the image to the user interface, it is cropped like this ([cropped zero image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfLdz.png)). Is there a way to allow the image to scale to the size of the button when I resize the button? Thank you!

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lontronix.calculator.Calculator">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/Filler_Text"
        android:textSize="35pt" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/zero"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write these properties on your imageView.

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Or you can try a different scaleType, see below:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide